# PostgreSQL. PQputCopyData и PQputCopyEnd. Вопрос об ограничениях

Tags: postgresql

Ребят, разбираюсь с PQputCopyData и PQputCopyEnd
Пытаюсь сделать отправку буферов, на сервере сложить эти буферы и потом одним запросом выполнить Copy from stdin
Связал, всё работает. Но хотелось бы выслушать опытных ребят в плане безопасности такого решения.
Судя по доке и логике сервер принимает ( через PQputCopyData )  буфер и у себя хранит его.  т.е. таким образом мы накапливаем 10-20 буферов ( сервер их складывает в один ), потом исполняем PQputCopyEnd и наш запрос COPY начинает обрабатываться.

Вот какие вопросы возникли:
1) что, если один клиент отправил 10-20-100 и т.д. буферов и внезапно крашнулся клиент ( ну вдруг ) , что будет с этими буферами? Они так и останутся на сервере? Или же сервер вычистит данные у себя ?

2) Какой максимальный объём таких буферов можно закинуть на сервер, не случится ли какое-нибудь переполнение и не крашнется ли сервер?

по поводу второго вопроса ещё есть такое в документации: 
PQputCopyData: Она возвращает 1 - если данные были переданы, 0 - если они не попали в очередь, так как буферы были заполнены (это возможно только в неблокирующем режиме), или -1, если произошла ошибка.
Типа, как я понимаю, на сервере есть некоторое место под это?  т.е. если новый буфер не вкинуть ( заполнено место под него), то вернёт мне ноль ?

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` штука интересная. Через `COPY` работают pg_dump, pg_restore, даже потоковая репликация.

Всю трассировку расписывать не буду, можете посмотреть обработку начиная [вот отсюда](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/commands/copy.c#L820). А ближе к сути:

Когда вы вызываете `COPY FROM STDIN` СУБД переходит в особый протокол для режима COPY.  При этом процесс базы начинает в бесконечном цикле ожидать поступление новой строки (по символу перевода строки), для чего читает поступающие данные от клиента [в небольшой внутренний буфер](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/commands/copy.c#L217) размером в 64кб и разбирает эти данные на строки, которые передаёт уже системе записи в таблицы.

Поэтому для самой СУБД и не имеет значения, сколько раз сделали `PQputCopyData` на клиенте и какого размера. Читать будем строками через небольшой свой буфер. Заполнить память сервера буфером сетевого трафика при этом нам не даёт непосредственно протокол TCP. В сетевых системах вообще очень много буферов на разных уровнях...

> потом исполняем PQputCopyEnd и наш запрос COPY начинает обрабатываться.

Нет. Исполняется - то есть пишутся данные в таблицу - COPY по мере поступления данных. `PQputCopyEnd` лишь сообщает, что больше данных не будет, допиши пожалуйста всё что осталось и выходи из `COPY`.

> что, если один клиент отправил 10-20-100 и т.д. буферов и внезапно
>   крашнулся клиент ( ну вдруг ) , что будет с этими буферами? Они так и
>   останутся на сервере? Или же сервер вычистит данные у себя ?

Если клиент пропал по любой причине - то общавшийся с ним процесс базы завершит выполняемую транзакцию откатом, завершится сам и вернёт всю занимаемую собой память операционной системе. Postgresql использует процессную модель работы. С каждым подключённым клиентом общается отдельный процесс.

А так же у postgresql есть своё управление памятью, называемое `memory context`. Есть много контекстов памяти, например контекст запроса, контекст транзакции - при завершении (по любой причине) запроса полностью сбрасывается контекст запроса, при завершении транзакции - контекст транзакции, что освобождает используемую память. СУБД штука долгоживущая, за утечками памяти разработчики приглядывают.

Ну и сам COPY - это всегда транзакция, поэтому если не было в WAL отметки что транзакция завершена успешно - то всех этих записанных данных никто не увидит. А затем придёт autovacuum и пометит эти области датафайлов как свободное место и поверх база сможет писать что-нибудь другое нужное.

> 2) Какой максимальный объём таких буферов можно закинуть на сервер, не
>   случится ли какое-нибудь переполнение и не крашнется ли сервер?

Предела нет. Можно террабайты передавать спокойно. Переполнение не случится т.к. уровнями ниже лежит протокол TCP, который ограничит скорость передачи данных если клиент желает передавать данные быстрее чем их читает собеседник.

> PQputCopyData: Она возвращает 1 - если данные были переданы, 0 - если они не попали в очередь, так как буферы были заполнены (это возможно только в неблокирующем режиме)

А это речь как раз о TCP. Хотя вернее даже вовсе о сетевом взаимодействии. У отправителя данных тоже есть буфер для отправляемых по сети данных. Если буфер заполнен - то есть не то сеть медленная, не то проблемы с сетью какие, не то принимающая сторона ещё не подтвердила приём этих данных - в общем это индикатор того, что приложению надо подождать. Если вы делаете запись данных в блокирующем режиме - вы просто подождёте пока буфер отправки станет посвободнее, запишете туда свои данные и вам вызов функции вернёт управление. А вот если вы в неблокирующем режиме вызываете функцию - то ей и писать данные некуда и подождать она не может, т.к. должна быть неблокирующая. Поэтому и появляется третье состояние "это не ошибка, пожалуйста, попробуйте ещё раз попозже"

Comment: т.е. если я от правил один буфер, он его ещё не успел записать в базу, а я отправляю ещё один , то PQputCopyData вернёт мне ноль?
или он просто подождёт и попробует сам отправить ещё раз?

Comment: Если вы перевели pq в неблокирующий режим - то получив 0 вы должны повторить чуть позже сами. Если вы в блокирующем режиме - PQputCopyData вернуть 0 не может. Только успех или ошибку. Отправку подождёт сам.